# Reading Data from Realm Database (Swift)

Tags: swift, database, synchronization, realm

I am new to Realm DataBase and I need a way to read data from realmCloud, but from two different app projects. The way I have tried to implement this is by using query-synced realm. At the moment I'm using a singe realm user to write the data in one app, and the same realm user to read data from another app. The problem is that making a query from the second app(the one used for reading) doesn't return any realm objects ( I have also noticed that user identifier is different from the first one, and also the user permissions are nil.

I have tried setting permissions directly from RealmStudio since documentation is not precise on how to set them from code

```
func openRealm() {
    do {
        realm = try Realm(configuration: SyncUser.current!.configuration())
        let queryResults = realm.objects(*className*.self)
        let syncSubscription = queryResults.subscribe()
        let notificationToken = queryResults.observe() { [weak self] (changes) in
            switch (changes) {
            case .initial: print(queryResults)
            case .error(let error): print(error)
            default: print("default")
            }
        }
        for token in queryResults {
            print(token.tokenString)
        }
        syncSubscription.unsubscribe()
        notificationToken.invalidate()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This function prints the data in one app project, but used in another app project with the same user logged in, and the same *classFile* referenced in the project, it does not. (note that `SyncUser.current.identifier` is different also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

Some of these calls are asynchronous and the code in your question is going out of scope before the data is sync'd (retreived). The bottom line is code is faster than the internet and you need to design the flow of the app around async calls; don't try to work with the data until it's available.

For example

```
    let notificationToken = queryResults.observe() { [weak self] (changes) in
       //here is where results are fully populated
    }

    // this code may run before results are populated //
    for token in queryResults {
        print(token.tokenString)
    }
```

Also, `let notificationToken` is a local var and goes out of scope before the results are populated as well.

These issues are super easy to fix. First is to keep the notification token alive while waiting for results to be populated and the second is to work with the results inside the closure, as that's when they are valid.

```
var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil //a class var

func openRealm() {
    do {
        let config = SyncUser.current?.configuration()
        let realm = try Realm(configuration: config!)
        let queryResults = realm.objects(Project.self)
        let syncSubscription = queryResults.subscribe(named: "my-projects")
        self.notificationToken = queryResults.observe() { changes in
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                print("notification: initial results are populated")
                queryResults.forEach { print($0) }
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                print("notification: results, inserted, deleteed or modified")
                insertions.forEach { print($0) } //or mods or dels
            case .error(let error):
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

deinit {
   self.notificationToken?.invalidate()
}
```

The other advantage of keeping that token (and its corresponding code) alive is when there are further changes, your app will be notified. So if another project is added for example, the code in the 'changes' section will run and display that change.

Comment: Hello Jay! Thank you very much. All of your mentions are correct, but I also want to add, for everyone who has the same problem, the fact that when i call SyncUser.logIn(*login parameters'), somehow the user that was logged in before remains cached, and this also creates inconsistent query results. The fix I applied, together with your suggestions, was : for user in SyncUser.all {
            user.value.logOut()
        } and then calling SyncUser.logIn

Comment: @OctavianMilea Yep - for sure, Realm remembers the last user that was logged in, however, it should not create inconsistent query results unless the query is tied to a particular user. For example a query `realm.objects(Project.self).filter("owner = %@", SyncUser.current!.identity!)` will return the results for the user that created that object as long as the owner property was populated when saving. If you change that to the query like shown in my question, it will return ALL projects regardless of user. If it's not working that way for you, post another question and we'll take a look.

Comment: it was very strange because when i first builded the app, even if the realm path and user credentials were the same, the user identity property was different from the other project, only after i logged out all the users and logged in again, the user identity was the same as in the other app